# Capistrano 3 runs every command twice (new install) - Configuration issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, capistrano, capistrano3

I just completed my capistrano installation for the first time. Most of everything is left to default settings, I configured my server, its authentification, and the remote folder, as well as the access to my git repository.

I use capistrano to deploy php code to my server.

*cap staging deploy* and *cap production deploy* function, but **they run every command twice**. It sometimes causes problems when those tasks are executed too quickly on the server, returning error codes, which stops the deploying process.

an example of my output when running *cap staging deploy*

```
DEBUG[47ecea59] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d ~/www/test_server/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/www/test_server/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on ftp.cluster013.ovh.net
DEBUG[47ecea59] Command: if test ! -d ~/www/test_server/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/www/test_server/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG[c450e730] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d ~/www/test_server/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/www/test_server/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi on ftp.cluster013.ovh.net
DEBUG[c450e730] Command: if test ! -d ~/www/test_server/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '~/www/test_server/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
```

It does the same with every single task, except the one I defined myself (in my deploy.rb, I defined a :set_distant_server task that moves around files with server info)

I am pretty sure I missed something during the initial configuration.

Here is my capfile, still to default settings :

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
#require 'capistrano/bundler'
#require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
#require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

Followed by my deploy.rb file:
    # config valid only for Capistrano 3.1
    lock '3.2.1'

```
set :scm, :git
set :application, 'Application name'
# I use token authentification
set :repo_url, 'https://XXXXXXXXXXX:@XXXXXXX.git'

set :role, 'web'


# Default value for :log_level is :debug
set :log_level, :debug
set :tmp_dir, 'www/test_server/tmp'
set :keep_releases, 8


role :deploy_server, "XXXuser_name@XXXX_server"

task :set_distant do
    on roles(:deploy_server) do
        execute 'echo ------------******* STAGING *******------------'
        execute 'cp ~/www/test_server/current/access_distant.php ~/www/test_server/current/access.php'
        execute 'cp ~/www/test_server/current/session_distant.php     ~/www/test_server/current/session.php'
    end
end


after "deploy:finished", :set_distant
```

Here is my staging.rb, much shorter:

```
 server 'XXX_server', user: 'XXXuser_name', roles: %w{web}, port: 22, password: 'XXXpassword'
 set :deploy_to, '~/www/test_server'
 set :branch, 'staging'
```

And my production.rb, very similar:

```
 server 'XXX_server', user: 'XXXuser_name', roles: %w{web}, port: 22, password: 'XXXpassword'
 set :deploy_to, '~/www/beta/'
```

I'm pretty sure I missed a step in all the prerequisites to make it run nicely. I am new to ruby, to gems, and didn't use shell for a very long time.

Does anyone see why those commands are run twice, and how I could fix it?

In advance, many many  thanks.

Additional info:
Ruby version:  ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]

Capistrano version: cap -V
Capistrano Version: 3.2.1 (Rake Version: 10.1.0)

I did not create a Gemfile or set it up, I understood it was not needed in Capistrano 3. Anyway, I would not know how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having this same issue and realized I didn't need both

```
role :web
```

and

```
server '<server>'
```

I got rid of role :web and that got rid of the 2nd execution.

Comment: Actually, I even had to remove the  roles: %w{web}, in the server definition.

Comment: had the same issue when using `server` twice (in both deploy.rb and deploy/production.rb)